# Org Mode LaTeX Export - Making TODOs red

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am using Org Mode within Emacs and I am using the Export to LaTeX option. The output is fine, however I would love to show:

- TODOs as red
- DONEs as green

So they stand out.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Modyfing the corresponding function from ox-latex.el

I copied the  org-latex-format-headline-default-function from ox-latex.el to my .emacs and added the two cases TODO and DONE. I recommend not replacing the original function but putting this in your .emacs.

It will make any "TODO" containing string red, any "DONE" one green when you export to LaTeX. Make sure that you put

#+Latex_header: \usepackage{xcolor}

in your org heading.
You can just edit the string after "format" to customize it.
You can as well add more cases if you have other todo keywords.

```
(defun org-latex-format-headline-colored-keywords-function
    (todo todo-type priority text tags info)
        (concat
           (cond ((string= todo "TODO")(and todo (format "{\\color{red}\\bfseries\\sffamily %s} " todo)))
   ((string= todo "DONE")(and todo (format "{\\color{green}\\bfseries\\sffamily %s} " todo))))
            (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
            text
            (and tags
            (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
    (mapconcat (lambda (tag) (org-latex-plain-text tag info))
           tags ":")))))

(setq org-latex-format-headline-function 'org-latex-format-headline-colored-keywords-function)
```

Comment: this answer seems basically correct. Just a couple of points to note. You should rename the default function and then do a setq to set org-latex-format-heading-function to the name of your function. Check the docs for that variable to get a description of the arguments your function must accept and what they mean. When you have more than 1 logical test, use something like cond rather than multiple if statements to improve clarity. I would also consider using todo-type, which is a symbol rather than todo, which is a string as it will usually make for clearer code and is often more efficient.

Comment: I did the setq and replaced the if statements by cond and it works. I was not able to use todo-type instead of string-comparison with todo. Doc says, that todo-type can be one of symbols todo, done or nil but the exporter says that it does not know the symbol done.

Comment: Would it be possible that this gets either accepted or I receive requests for making it acceptable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. I have only recently needed it.

Comment: For me this solution suddenly does not work anymore. The problem seems to be that `org-latex-format-headline-function` does not pass an `info` parameter anymore in newer org-mode versions. Removing it from the parameter list (i.e. `(todo todo-type priority text tags)`) solves the problem for me and everything seems to work, but I have no idea whether this might produce some unwanted side effects.

Comment: Also see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74694/how-to-change-formatting-todo-in-org-modes-latex-pdf-output/74695#74695